# What should be the name for the new [*vcf*] tag related to bioinformatics vcf file format?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

We need a new tag that covers the widely used vcf file format in bioinformatics. But the [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) tag is already taken. What should the new tag be called?

[Search for: vcf [bioinformatics]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vcf+%5Bbioinformatics%5D)
140 results

[Search for: [vcf]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf)
189 results

**Current [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) tag info:**

> vCard is a file format(.vcf) standard for electronic business cards. vCards are often attached to e-mail messages, but can be exchanged in other ways, such as on the World Wide Web or instant messaging. They can contain name and address information, phone numbers, e-mail addresses, URLs, logos, photographs, and audio clips. **Do not use this tag for genetics related VCF files.**
> *(boldface mine)*

Despite the **above tag info**, confusion persists:
[Search for: [vcf] bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvcf%5D+bioinformatics)
15 results

**FAQs:**

**What is vcf file format?**

Bioinformatics SE [vcf] tag:
[VCF, acronym for Variant Calling Format, is a text file type used to store information regarding genetic variants.](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vcf)
[The Variant Call Format (VCF) Version 4.2 Specification](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf)
[Variant Call Format - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format)

**If only people would actually read the tag info!**

I agree that, unfortunately, many users often skip the tag info. Using the proposed separate tags ([vcf-variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-variant-call-format) and [vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcard)) is more specific than the current single [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) tag. It arguably does not require reading the tag info. Thus, it should help alleviated the issue.

Please suggest below better names and tag info to help people to add tags without reading the tag info. And please suggest in a separate question how to make tag info more visible/obvious, how to make tagging more accurate, etc.

**The bioinformatics `vcf`-related tag is not needed.**

The bioinformatics `vcf`-related tag helps users find other related questions.

This tag also helps point users to the many widely used tools for `vcf` manipulation (`vcftools`, `bcftools`, `GATK`, `PyVCF`, etc). Using these tools helps avoid reinventing the wheel and promotes reuse of open source software. Some users try to solve `vcf`-related tasks using **only** general-purpose programming tools. Some users are not even aware of the format they are using and of the specialized bioinformatics tools designed to easily manipulate `vcf` data. Examples:
[extract all rows of specific column after comparing two files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21121098/967621)
[Extract specific word matching the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51132611/967621)

**I find [vcf-variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-variant-call-format) a terrible tag name. Using [variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variant-call-format) is better.**

It is true that this tag name is not pretty! But the `vcf` part of the tag is needed because much fewer people know the full name ("variant call format") compared to the abbreviation `vcf`. Most call `vcf` files using the abbreviation. So the users will most likely find the tag by starting to type `vcf...`, which then will show the full tag name. The `vcf`-related tag is similar in this respect to tags such as [bam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml), etc. The bioinformatics related `vcf` tag got unlucky and must have a longer name to help disambiguate it from the `vcard` related tag.

Comment: [variant-calling-format] and rename the existing [vcf] to [vcard-format] and block [vcf] so nobody gets to claim their "vcf" is the *correct* file extension.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: That looks like an answer. Why not post it as such?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Mostly because I don't know what I'm talking about. But hey, I've never let that stop me before, so....

Comment: "Despite the above tag info" If only people would actually read that.

Comment: @Mast Thank you. I edited the post to include this.

Comment: existing tag [tag:vcf] has had 180 questions in 11 years; merge it with [tag:vcard] and use `vcf` for this.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here's one proposal on how to handle the situation:

- Add a [variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variant-call-format) (or [vcf-variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-variant-call-format)) tag to cover the relatively new vcf format.

  - A clean up activity will need to be done to find where [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) has been used in conjunction with its Variant Calling Format meaning.
- Merge the existing [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) and [vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcard) tags and
- Maybe rename [vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcard) to [vcf-vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-vcard) to keep the vcf part around.
- Block the [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) tag from being used.

Now, why move questions to a different tag when there is an existing tag that's been happily providing categorization for questions about the vCard format for years? Mainly so that no one can complain that `vcf` is the "one true file extension" for one or another program or format.

Comment: +1 for a good compromise solution. Note that the vcf format is **very** common in bioinformatics. Also, few people refer to it by its full name. Most people refer to it by its `vcf` abbreviation. So the new tag should probably be [tag:vcf-variant-call-format] .

Comment: Also, some links I provided, alas, incorrectly say that *calling* instead of *call*. Just to reiterate, it should probably be `[vcf-variant-call-format]`.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I didn't look past the first link. I do wish there was a way we could have "conditional synonyms" where someone could type `vcf` and get [variant-call-format] if they'd added [genetics] or something and [vcard-format] if they used [phone] or [outlook] or whatever. Alack alas.

Comment: *A clean up activity will need to be done to find where vcf has been used in conjunction with its Variant Calling Format meaning.* Another good point! I will be happy to clean up after we have the new tag.

Comment: I don't really see how [tag:vcf] is any different from [tag:vcard], though. VCard is a file format, that saves as a .vcf file. I think we can just merge vcf and vcard, and avoid creating a vcard-format tag.

Comment: @ErikA Technically, vCard is a "data format". That is most often expressed as a file format, but I remember when it was all the rage to embed vCards on your "weblog", just before the page counter, but after the "best viewed in Netscape Navigator" gif :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, just like jpg is a file/data format and often embedded and loaded without permanently storing it. That it can be embedded is not that relevant. I don't think a separate tag here adds anything.

Comment: @ErikA Fair enough. You're right that having too many tags for the same idea is bad news.

Comment: People refer to vcf in both contexts often, so [vcf-variant-call-format] and [vcf-vcard] allows to easily find the tag we are looking for when we type vcf.

Comment: @zeehio This might make life easier for the [tag:vcard] users. Should your proposal of [vcf-variant-call-format] and [vcf-vcard] be incorporated into the above answer, or should it be made into a separate answer?

Comment: To be honest I'm new to meta and I don't know the conventions well enough... If @HereticMonkey does not like the suggestion I made I could make it into a separate answer... I guess.

Comment: @zeehio I actually had [vcf-vcard] up there for a bit, but ErikA reminded me that we already have [vcard]... I have no hat in this game, so I'll just add it as an option. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: It seems that this answer is a hands-down winner. Thank you Heretic Monkey for the answer, zeehio, Erik A and TylerH for valuable suggestions and discussion.

Comment: For the record: While I support the general thrust of this answer, I find both [tag:vcf-variant-call-format] and [tag:vcf-vcard] to be terrible tag names. Omitting the `vcf` part would be better (and, as explained in my own answer, the bioinformatics related tag is plain unnecessary).

Answer (score 10):

### The tag is not needed at all

Not every file format needs its own tag. Sure, VCF *is* a widely used format in bioinformatics, but then there are <140 questions *total* about VCF files, and we have a separate https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com — which, sure enough, has a [[vcf]](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vcf) tag (and there it makes sense).

Bioinformatics questions that are asked on Stack Overflow (rather than on Bioinformatics.SE) should be focussed on generalisable programming concepts, they don’t need to mention every used technology or file format in its tag: likewise, bwa-mem, STAR and DESeq2 are extremely widely used technologies in bioinformatics, and I would strongly oppose introducing tags for them.

The existing questions should be either migrated to the Bioinformatics.SE or can be kept for posteriority without a corresponding tag.

That said, I support Heretic’s suggestion of removing the currently ambiguous [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) to [vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcard).

Comment: Could SE use a disambiguation process like wikipedia.org? Try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCF

Comment: @lit Could? — Yes. Would it be a good idea? — Very likely, also yes. But the current system doesn’t allow this, it would have to be implemented as a completely new feature and while its scope at first glance appears small we shouldn’t underestimate the effort this would take.

Comment: Estimating software development is a mysterious alchemy. It often presents as an iceberg with 90% not visible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for the raising this important issue. I edited my answer to address this. I agree that many tools such as *bwa-mem, STAR and DESeq2* do not need their own tags on SO. File formats are more in the grey area... +1 for the thoughtful contrarian view.

Comment: Agreed, we could make the same statement about [sam]- the format on bioinformatics SE and Simple Asynchronous Messaging on SO (although [fasta] and [fastq] are used on both)

Answer (score 8):

## Tracking answer - ALL DONE!

This answer is for tracking the progress of this task. When you complete the subtask, please mark it as done, put your name and date.
**Legend: [TODO] = not done, [x] = done.**

1. [x] Create new tag: [vcf-variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-variant-call-format). Propose [tag wiki/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vcf-variant-call-format/info).  (Timur Shtatland, Oct 1 '20) Tag wiki/info was approved Oct 7 '20.
2. [x] Fix questions incorrectly tagged with old tag [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf). Change to tag [vcf-variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-variant-call-format) as needed. [Search for: [vcf] bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvcf%5D+bioinformatics). Old: 15 results, new: 0 results. (Timur Shtatland, Oct 1 '20)
3. [x] Add tag [vcf-variant-call-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-variant-call-format) to vcf + bioinformatics related questions. [Search for: vcf [bioinformatics]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vcf+%5Bbioinformatics%5D). Old: 140 results. New: 0 relevant results, everything tagged that needed tagging. [Search for: vcf [bioinformatics] -[vcf-variant-call-format]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=vcf%20%5bbioinformatics%5d%20-%5bvcf-variant-call-format%5d) (Timur Shtatland, Oct 5 '20)
4. [x] Flag the question for moderator attention, with the message: *"Could you please feature this question so it gets advertised on SO main? This will attract some more votes / opinions. Thank you!"* (Timur Shtatland, Oct 6 '20). The question was featured Oct 14-20 '20 by Machavity, and attracted more valuable votes, opinions, answers and comments.
5. [x] Merge the existing [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) and [vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcard) tags and
6. [x] Rename [vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcard) to [vcf-vcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf-vcard) to keep the `vcf` part around.
7. [x] Block the [vcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) tag from being used. Tasks 5-7 completed on Oct 27 '20 by Machavity.
8. [x] Flag this answer for moderator attention, asking to please carry out the previous 3 items (items 5-7), because I do not have enough privileges (Timur Shtatland, Oct 21 '20).

---

**REFERENCES:**

[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/967621)

Comment: Done. Technically #5 and #7 are the same, since the synonym blocks any recreation of the tag

Comment: @Machavity Thank you very much for the help throughout this process!